# Load function doesn't work with IE

Tags: jquery

I can't get load function to work with IE. In Google Chrome my website runs fine.
I tried to fix the issue with "no-cache" strategy, but no luck. What else should i do to make it work with IE?

Source:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript" src="ayarlar/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

</script>


<style type="text/css">

.slaytGosterimi {
    position: relative;

left:10%;
top:15%;

}
body {

background:#000000 ;
}
.ustBackground {
position: relative;
left:15%;
width:70%;
height:100%;
background:#F4F4F4;


}


</style>


<div class="ustBackground">

<!--Slayt gösterisi içeriği!-->
<div class="slaytGosterimi" id="slaytGosterimi">
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#slaytGosterimi").load('slaytGosterim.htm');
</script>
</div>
<!--Slayt gösterisi içeriği!-->

</div>
```

Comment: Why the extra `</script>` after you load jQuery?

Comment: What "exactly" does _"does not work"_ mean?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a description of a problem. Is `load()` not being called? Does it throw an error? Is ajax request actually being made if you check it in Fiddler? Does content of `#slaytGosterimi` appear broken?

Comment: @Sparky672 I meant "not compatible" since IE does not load the other page.

Comment: It is also worth noting that naming things in code using language other than english is a really bad habit. It is also much less likely you'll be able to get help with it, shall you need it.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc Didn't see it, thanks.

Comment: @liho1eye where you saw such thing? I can see only non English comments which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @gcx, Now you say _"non compatible"_.  That is not only inaccurate, it's another wholly inadequate problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in the `<head>` section and change to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slaytGosterimi").load('slaytGosterim.htm');
});
</script>
```

As you got the script written inside the element it's trying to access, that element wasn't ready yet.

As rule of thumb, always wrap code that access DOM elements inside `$(document).ready()` no matter where it's placed - don't count on the browser to be forgiving.